# Check a checkbox on a HTML page in VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net, checkbox

I'm trying to get my program to check a box on a webpage and it always comes up with an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

here's the code:    `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chkAge").SetAttribute("checked", "true")`
and here's the code for the website:
    `<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkAge" name="chkAge">`

any idea what my error could be?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason - document is not ready when you're trying to execute this code. Try this code in [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) Event:

```
Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chkAge").SetAttribute("checked", "true")
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason it still comes up with that error, although if I spam click on the page it works just fine. doesn't make any sense..